# Generate a set of unique keys that can be validated without keeping a white-list

Tags: c, hash, key, crc

I need to generate sets of 10 bytes unique IDs. These sets can be quite big (i.e. 10000 values) and are checked by a limited-memory device for validity. So someone enters one of the IDs in the device, and the device should be able to discern whether the ID is genuine (generated by me).
The basic way would be to store in the device's memory the same set of IDs and check against the list, but I can't use all of that memory.
A second way I thought would be to use a CRC or a hash function: for instance all the IDs whose CRC is X are enabled. The problem here is that I should iterate through all the possible combination of IDs to find the ones giving the right CRC.
Ideally, I would like to find one/two functions that work like this:

```
 uint8_t * generate_ID(uint16_t index);
 bool is_valid validate_key(uint8_t * ID);
 //optional
 uint16_t index find_index(uint8_t * ID);

 //example
 //generate id value from index 0
 uint8_t ID[10] = generate_ID(0)
 //id is now {0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b}

 bool is_valid = validate_key(ID);
 //is_valid is True
 uint16_t index = find_index(ID);
 //index is now 0
 ID[0] = 0xff; //change ID with random value
 is_valid = validate_key(ID);
 //is_valid is now False

 //BONUS: use also a "seed" value, so that I can differentiate through sets of ids:
 uint8_t * generate_ID(uint16_t index, uint16_t seed);
 bool is_valid validate_key(uint8_t * ID, uint16_t seed);
```

find_index() is optional because once I know the key is valid I can simply iterate through all indexes to find the matching index.
Basically, the generate_ID() function should be complex enough so that it won't be easily guessable if not knowing a decent amount of ID, yet able to be computed on an embedded CPU with limited horsepower (Cortex M0)

Comment: Are the symbols numeric (10 symbols) or alpha-numeric (36 symbols if fixed case, 62 if mixed case, 64 if you allow two special characters plus fixed characters). Assuming 64 values per symbol, then 10 symbols = 2^60 possible values, and say you allow 2^14 = 16384 of them, then you could use a 46 bit CRC. It wouldn't be that secure if someone knew it was based solely on a CRC. Using some xor pattern on the data could help a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 10 byte key is not enough to make anything secure.

You need a secure hash function such as SHA2-256 whose output is 32-byte in length. SHA2 can easily be implemented on most systems.

Your key needs two parts:

```
[text + hash]
```

The first part is like a "username" and the second part is like a "password"

You also need a "secret key". This key is an array of bytes which is stored in your software. You then add the "secret key" to your "username". Find the SHA2 hash for the resulting string. Now you have an output that is the length of original text + 32 bytes for the hash.

You can use this key as a unique verifiable ID.

To test they key's authenticity, take the "username" part and add your secret key. Take SHA2 of that string, the result should match "password"

If secrecy and uniqueness is not a big issue then you can use MD5 whose output is 16 bytes. Change plain text to binary so it can store more information in fewer bytes, and your final key will be only 20 bytes. You could cut that down a bit more but reducing to 10 bytes is not recommended.

Here is an example. I used SHA2 implementation from this link:
https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms (I am not sure if it works on a big-endian machine)

Any SHA2 implementation should work.

```
void sha2(BYTE* dst, const BYTE* src, int len)
{
    SHA256_CTX ctx;
    sha256_init(&ctx);
    sha256_update(&ctx, (const BYTE*)src, len);
    sha256_final(&ctx, (BYTE*)dst);
}

void create_verifiable_id(const BYTE* source, BYTE *uid)
{
    BYTE hash[32];
    sha2(hash, source, ID_SIZE);

    //combine source + hash
    memcpy(uid, source, ID_SIZE);
    memcpy(uid + ID_SIZE, hash, 32);
}

int test_verfiable_id(const BYTE *uid)
{
    BYTE hash[32];
    sha2(hash, uid, ID_SIZE);

    //hash should match the second part of uid
    return memcmp(hash, uid + ID_SIZE, 32) == 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    //use a number from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFF, store in buf (4 bytes)
    //this is the "plain text" portion
    int number = 0x12345678;
    BYTE buf[ID_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
    {
        buf[i] = number & 0xFF;
        number >>= 8;
    }

    //add sha2 to "plain text" to make verifiable id
    BYTE verifiable_id[32 + ID_SIZE];
    create_verifiable_id(buf, verifiable_id);

    printf("UID as hex string:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 32 + ID_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%02X", verifiable_id[i] & 0xFF);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Test (should succeed): %d\n", test_verfiable_id(verifiable_id));

    //change verifiable_id and test it again
    verifiable_id[0]++;
    printf("Test (should fail): %d\n", test_verfiable_id(verifiable_id));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's a good idea! Do you think I can use the same approach with AES128 which I have hardware functions for?
Uniqueness is important, I don't want two IDs to collide, security is a bit less important.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use AES in that way. The encryption blocks are unrelated so you have to use simple ECB mode which is weak. Also AES is a 2-way encryption, whereas hash functions are 1-way. MD5 is vulnerable to attack but it's better than AES in this case. SHA2 is better, it is used in password verification which is more applicable here.

Comment: @Vitomakes, making a hash function from an encryption algorithm is not difficult, you have only to encrypt the source text into blocks of fixed size and  then XOR all of them together (this is an example of just one way of doing) with a block size equal to the size of the hash you want.   But what are you using that only supports AES, and no hashing at all?  To avoid colliding you need large keys, you cannot avoid it completely, but on a probabilistic way (the space of source texts is always bigger than the space of hash keys)

Comment: @LuisColorado AES is just "easier" because I have hardware peripherals for that on my CPU and I don't need to code anything at all. BTW the basic AES block is 16 bytes, so if I make the ID longer (exactly 16 bytes), I can just use 1 whole block with no risk of collision, right?

Comment: @Vitomakes, you can use e.g. a 32 bytes blocksize (two blocks of AES code, or even better, use a 30 byte block size and lose two bytes from each AES buffer, that will give less coherency between AES buffers) and get wider hash space, and you'll get less chance to collisions.  Do you actually have AES by hardware but no hash function at all?  strange.

Comment: @LuisColorado I admit my ignorance, I don't understand why I should use hashing.
My simple idea is to do create an ID 16 bytes long like:
clearID = | sequential number | fixed value | random nonce |
ID = enc_AES128(clearID, secretkey)
In this way, on the "reader" device, I can decode the ID, and check for the presence of the "fixed value" to detect whether it is a genuine ID.
Or, maybe I can simply add a CRC before encryption. What are the limtiation of this arpproach?
Yes, only HW AES because it's used in some radio protocol for encryption, it's a small CPU.

Comment: AES needs a 16-byte IV in addition to the key, so the output will be at least 32 bytes (16 bytes IV + 16 bytes AES block) Using AES without IV is a problem if the attacker sees many of your ciphers. You also have to include the "plain text" part in your ID key, that makes it worse for AES. SHA2 is easier for this purpose. If you are using a crypto library it wil already have SHA2. But you can find stand alone implementation for SHA2. See edit.

Comment: @Vitomakes, hashing normally is used to build a hash table, that has an access time of _O(0)_.  It also allow you to cache the active sessions by maintaining only the key.  Your ID must be the result of a hash function, because of its properties (it uses a uniformly vast key space, so the probability of colliding is low) when two keys lead to different hashes, you can be sure that keys are different (by comparing only the hashes) but if they are equal, you have to compare the keys.  This can accelerate the processing time.

Comment: @Vitomakes, you can use also the hash function as some means of signing a message, so if you send a catenation of the original key, plus some private key, as a hash value (with the original key) then you can validate that the origin of such hash was you, but nobody else is supposed to do (they don't have the key catenated to the original key to generate the hash) This allows you to somewhat trust the info passed by your client, and not have to store it locally.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, AES needs a IV _if you are using it to encrypt._  The specification of AES proposes a way to use this IV.  But this time you are using it to hash text info (which is a process that intrinsically losses information in the way) and it has the proper properties to be used as a secure hash function (nonlinearity, uniform distribution, etc.)  One requirement is not to implement SHA1, due to lack of resources.  On this scenario, I think it's better to use the hardware implementation of AES than to implement (in software) a cryptographically secure hash function as SHA1.

Comment: @LuisColorado my suggested solution was to combine plain-text + cipher. The attacker can see both. This is giving away a lot of information. AES is not meant for that. If you are proposing a different solution please put that in an answer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, yes, you are using the hash to sign a text, an IV is also unencrypted text, well, you can add an IV before calculating the hash.  But as the hash is used only to verify the signature, and you don't have the encrypted text (only the hash generated from it)  I think it a good idea to add enthropy, but I don't consider it added security.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way to do this is with a modular multiplicative inverse, as I describe in my blog post here: http://blog.mischel.com/2017/06/20/how-to-generate-random-looking-keys/.

The idea is that you map the numbers from 1 to some number x so that each number generates a unique value within that same range. So, for example, the mapping might be:

```
1 -> 9875
2 -> 362
3 -> 5247
...
```

This is a reversible calculation. So if f(1) => 9875, then g(9875) => 1.

In the code shown in the blog post, you can change the mapping by modifying the `x` and `m` values.

If you want the keys to be alphanumeric, then you need to encode them after generating the integer. And then you'll have to decode them back to an integer after the user enters it and before you try to validate.

So, for your validation, set `m` to a very large number. Set `x` appropriately, preferably a prime number larger than `m`. Generate the first 10,000 keys using those values. On the device that is supposed to validate these numbers, just supply the `x` and `m` values, and the maximum index (i.e. 10,000).

So a user enters the key they were given. You run the reverse of the key generation and get a number between 1 and 10,000. You know that the number is valid. If your reverse calculation returns a number that's less than 1 or greater than 10,000, then that key isn't valid.

You could extend this to multiple devices by just giving each device the start and end values that it considers valid. The reverse key calculation is the same, regardless.

This technique ensures uniqueness. Security is ... mostly through obscurity. If somebody knows the algorithm being used, including the `x` and `m` values, and knows the range of numbers that a device is set to accept, then he could generate keys to defeat the system. Whether that's a problem is something only you can answer. What is the risk of somebody trying to defeat your system, and what is the cost if they succeed?